# Symfony2 and NGINX - auth_basic allways asks for the password

Tags: nginx, http-authentication

I have a project written using Symfony2 framework and running on Nginx server.
The goal is to protect it with auth_basic.

What I did in nginx config file:

```
location ~ \.php(/|$) {
auth_basic 'RESTRICTED ACCESS';
auth_basic_user_file /var/www/my.passwd;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
```

}

But there, when I try to access the page and i fill in the username and password, It asks me the same again and again.

I have some redirects on the page:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
     rewrite ^ http://www.example.com$uri permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  ssl_certificate ssl2013/myssl.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key ssl2013/myssl.key;
  keepalive_timeout 70;

  set $asset_dir /var/www/example.com/web/bundles/mdpimain;

  server_name www.example.com;
  root /var/www/example.com/web;

  # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
  rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

  # rewrite home
  rewrite ^/home/? / permanent;

  # remove trailing slash
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

  # remove index.php
  rewrite ^[/](.*)/index\.php$ /$1 permanent;

  # sitemap redirection
  rewrite ^/sitemap_(.*)$ /sitemap/$1 last;

  location / {
    index app.php;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
      break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
  }
```

**EDIT1.**

Another detail: the password and user I am using are ok because no logs in the nginx error.log, so there is a redirect problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the `$remote_user`, if empty, return 403.

**EDIT** This works for me.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    auth_basic 'RESTRICTED ACCESS';
    auth_basic_user_file /var/web/my.passwd;

    set $ok "no";
    if ($remote_user ~ ^$) { break; }
    if ($remote_user != '') { set $ok "yes"; }

    if ($ok != "yes") {
        return 403;
    }

    # Path for static files
    root /var/web/public_html;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass        127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens, still the 'RESTRICTED ACCESS' dialog and asking me for the username and password

Comment: Have you reload or restart? And maybe try moving the auth section out of php block?

Comment: Moving this outside, same problem.

Comment: And also, each time I have to fill in the auth_basic info, a new access log is created

Comment: I just tried, and it works for me. Modify that to suit your configuration.

Comment: I am still geting the exact same problem as before, probably a symfony config problem then... Hm, strange, any idea?

Comment: Do you see the user in the access log? You should see it. It's probably one of your rewrite rules.

Comment: No, I am getting this: `xx.xxx.xx.xxx - user [21/Jul/2014:16:38:54 +0200] "GET /app_dev.php/ HTTP/1.1" 401 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
xx.xxx.xx.xxx - user [21/Jul/2014:16:38:58 +0200] "GET /app_dev.php/ HTTP/1.1" 401 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"`

Comment: I just tried the auth_basic in another non symfony project and it works perfectly well. I think that symfony is somehow not keeping the cache there.